# Difference between rpm -ivh <package> and yum install <package>

Tags: linux, yum, rpm, package-management

Supposing that I am going to install a package, what's the difference between these two commands: `rpm -ivh <package>` and `yum install <package>`

same question for example with `rpm -Uvh <package>` and `yum update <package>` (for updating issue)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `rpm` you must specify where to get the file with the new version of the package.

`yum`, which is a more intelligent management system, try to find a new version of the package in their repositories, will look for the package dependencies, will look for the fastest repository mirror (and make a lot of other pleasantrie)

Comment: For the difference between -ivh and -Uvh see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794089/difference-between-rpm-ivh-and-rpm-uvh/27794125. Basically `U` will install and remove old versions and `i` will just install.

Comment: Additionally, you can use `yum localinstall <packagename>` to intelligently install dependencies as needed.

Comment: Furthermore, `yum` is the default package manager for Enterprise Linux (RHEL/CentOS) but other distributions may use other managers such as `apt-get`.

Answer (score 5):

- `rpm` - RPM Package Manager.
- `yum` - is  an  interactive,  rpm  based,  package  manager.

there is no difference if you're installing single file as both `yum` which is wrapper for `rpm` and they both offers same core functionality, however `yum` can do more as `yum` works with repo(s) and it can handle updates & has plugins, while `rpm` works with file(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know  if a package was installed using rpm or through yum, issue 
  "yum list installed" and  check the 3rd column. If it is:

---"installed" then it was installed using rpm command

---"@base" or other repo, it means it has been installed through yum from a repo

---"@"example_filename. A filename after @ means it has been installed using "yum localinstall package.rpm", so a local rpm install through yum

It's best to install through yum because it also resolves dependencies. And if you compile from source code&install (e.g. you can't find the needed package for your distro), these installs are not registered in rpmdb so yum and rpm will not display and manage those installations afterwards.